# Linq overloading where clause to exclude a specific type

Tags: linq, methods, dictionary, where-clause

I am implementing an extension method that returns `TKey` with `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` as an argument. If `TValue` is `double`, the method is likely to return a `TKey` with the highest value. Otherwise, it will randomly return a `TKey`.

```
    public static TKey Sample<TKey>(this IDictionary<TKey, double> probabilityTable, Random r)
    {
        probabilityTable.Normalize();

        var roll = r.NextDouble();
        var temp = 0.0;
        foreach (var key in probabilityTable.Keys)
        {
            temp += probabilityTable[key];
            if (roll <= temp)
                return key;
        }

        return default(TKey);
    }

    public static TKey Sample<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, Random r)
    {
        return dictionary.Skip(r.Next(dictionary.Count)).FirstOrDefault().Key;
    }

    public static IDictionary<TKey, double> Normalize<TKey>(this IDictionary<TKey, double> probabilityTable)
    {
        if (probabilityTable.Any(x => x.Value < 0))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("probabilityTable", "Probability is expected to be positive.");

        var sum = probabilityTable.Sum(x => x.Value);

        if (Math.Abs(sum - 1) > 1e-8)
            return probabilityTable.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value / sum);

        if (Math.Abs(sum) < 1e-8)
            return probabilityTable.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => 1.0 / probabilityTable.Count);

        return probabilityTable;
    }
```

The problem is that `Sample<TKey, TValue>` is always called even with `double` of `TValue`. Any way that I can specify the type `TValue` exclude double with where clause? i.e. `where TValue: !double`

The code that calls the extension function is below:

```
        var r = new Random();
        var pt = new Dictionary<char, double> {{'A', 0.1}, {'B', 0.2}, {'C', 0.7}};
        var ct = new Dictionary<char, char> {{'A', 'D'}, {'B','E'}, {'C', 'F'}};
        Console.WriteLine(pt.Sample(r)); // expected to return 'C' mostly but uniformly returns key
        Console.WriteLine(ct.Sample(r));
```

Comment: If I run this code (taking out the call to `Normalize` which isn't shown here) I get the distributions I'd expect for both `double` and `char`. Maybe your `Normalize` method is broken?

Comment: @Rawling Sorry, it's just a normalization method for cateogrical distribution. I added it.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint are not part of the signature, maybe the following link helps you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx